# Verifying if a point is inside a cube in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have created a cube as:

```
var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 
       0xffff00,wireframe: true } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial );
cube.position.x = p.x;
cube.position.y = p.y;
cube.position.z = p.z;
scene.add(cube);
```

p is a input point to my function. So this code creates a cube at position p and adds it to the scene.

How can I check that some point,say A, lies inside this cube? I couldn't find any helper function like containsPoint etc for Three.Mesh. I may do some additional checks to verify, but I am looking for a Three.js function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `THREE.Box3()` instance, using its `.setFromObject()` the cube as the parameter, then call `.containsPoint()`, passing the point you want to check as the parameter to this method:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(2, 5, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));

var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "aqua",
  wireframe: true
}));
cube.position.set(0, 1, 0);
scene.add(cube);

var pointA = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
var pointB = new THREE.Vector3(2, 1, 0);
point(pointA, 0x00ff00);
point(pointB, "yellow");

function point(point, color) {
  p = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.25, 4, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: color
  }));
  p.position.copy(point);
  scene.add(p);
}

var bb = new THREE.Box3(); // for re-use
bb.setFromObject(cube);
console.log(bb);
console.log(bb.containsPoint(pointA), bb.containsPoint(pointB));

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think there is an issue here. BoundingBox has vertices in local coordinate system(centre of box as origin, and vertices determined by half of the size of box's dimensions) while point is in world coordinate system.Would it work?

Comment: @Mandroid Yes, you're correct, I've updated the answer and its code snippet, using just an instance of `THREE.Box3()`.

Comment: I don't think your solution works for a rotated box. Box3 is axis aligned.. so if the cube is rotated 45 degrees, the point in test on its Axis aligned box will give you false positives. I posted another reply showing you the problem.. the point that is red is still reported as "in" the box.

Comment: @prisoner849 I cloned your example to show the box3 version vs just converting the point to the object space and testing the coordinates, and added some animation so you can see how they both work.

Comment: Man. You saved me a life! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
cube.updateMatrixWorld(); //Make sure the object matrix is current with the position/rotation/scaling of the object...
var localPt = cube.worldToLocal(yourPoint.clone());  //Transform the point from world space into the objects space
if(Math.abs(localPt.x)<=0.5&&Math.abs(localPt.y)<=0.5&&Math.abs(localPt.z)<=0.5)
    console.log("Point is inside!"); //Check if all the axis are within the size of the cube.. if your cube sizes arent 1,1,1, you'll have to adjust these checks to be half of width/height/depth..
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 0):

@prisoner849
Your solution doesn't work if the box is rotated.
Here's an illustration of the problem. I render both solutions and you can see where the Box3 version breaks with the rotated cube, whereas the analytical once works.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(2, 5, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));
var boxDimensions = new THREE.Vector3(2,2,2);
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxDimensions.x,boxDimensions.y,boxDimensions.z), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "aqua",
  wireframe: true
}));
cube.position.set(0, 1, 0);
cube.rotation.y = Math.PI*0.25;
scene.add(cube);

var pointA = new THREE.Vector3(0.95, 0.95, 0.95);

var pointC = new THREE.Vector3(-0.65, 0.65, -0.65);
var pa = point(pointA, 0x00ff00);

var pc = point(pointC, 0x00ff00);

function point(point, color) {
  p = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.25, 4, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: color
  }));
  p.position.copy(point);
  scene.add(p);
  return p;
}

var bb = new THREE.Box3(); // for re-use
bb.setFromObject(cube);
console.log(bb);


function correctPointInBox(pt,cube,boxDim){
 cube.updateMatrixWorld(); //Make sure the object matrix is current with the position/rotation/scaling of the object...
var localPt = cube.worldToLocal(pt.clone());  //Transform the point from world space into the objects space
if(Math.abs(localPt.x)<=boxDim.x*0.5&&Math.abs(localPt.y)<=boxDim.y*0.5&&Math.abs(localPt.z)<=boxDim.z*0.5)
return true;
else
return false;
}


render();

function render() {
   pa.position.x = Math.sin(performance.now()*0.001)*2;
   pc.position.z = Math.cos(performance.now()*0.001)*2;

   if(bb.containsPoint(pa.position))
       pa.material.color.set("red")
   else 
       pa.material.color.set("green")

    if(correctPointInBox(pc.position,cube,boxDimensions))
         pc.material.color.set("red")
    else 
        pc.material.color.set("green")

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's an option too. But initially, there was no condition about rotation :) I've made kind of a synthesis of both solutions (have a look at `option 3` in `correctPointInBox` function): https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/173rnsws/

Comment: @prisoner849 OOoo yeah that's way better :D. That should be the main answer IMO.. post it and I'll upvote it!